# what to call "something that we desire"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Everyone has desire for something. A politician has 
desire for a position. An unemployed has desire for a job. A baby has desire for candy. The things which they have desire for have different names, but those are "**desired ones**".

Is there any word (noun) for "**something that is desired**"?

Example sentence:

> My baby loves teddy bear because it is her _________.

Comment: With the verb *desire* you do not need, and it is incorrect, to add the preposition *for*. Your sentences should all have the word *for* deleted from them. Without *for* they are all perfectly grammatical.

Comment: A wish (one) or a wish list (many)

Comment: It's a *desirable*.

Comment: My baby loves teddy bear because it is her _________.

Comment: @aswaaks: thanks. You don't need to reply to my comments, though; it's better if you just edit your question in response.

Answer (score 2):

A ***[wish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wish):***

> - A thing or event that is or has been desired; an object of desire:
>
>   - *the petitioners eventually got their wish*

(ODO)

Comment: On that note, a "desire" also works; If I were asked "what is your desire," I could answer "lunch" and be understood.

Answer (score 1):

**desideratum** (plural desiderata)

noun de·sid·er·a·tum \di-ˌsi-də-ˈrä-təm, -ˌzi-, -ˈrā-\

: something that is needed or wanted

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desideratum)

Answer (score 1):

[***Need***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/need) could be a candidate as it means:

> something that a person must have : something that is needed in order
>   to live or succeed or ***be happy***

"Our experienced staff will go out of their way to meet your every ***need***."

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 1):

***Desirable*** is the obvious replacement:

> She is well adjusted, mature, competent, and beautiful:   a very **desirable** woman.

Comment: It's used as an adjective there. Can it be used as a noun?

Comment: @sumelic:  not that I can immediately think of.  At least not other than "desirable object".

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

> **GOAL**
>
> : the object of a person’s ambition or effort; an aim or desired result [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/goal#goal__7)
>
> **END**
>
> : a goal or result that one seeks to achieve [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/end)
>
> **TARGET**
>
> : an objective or result toward which efforts are directed
> [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/target#target__6)
>
> **OBJECTIVE**
>
> : a thing aimed at or sought; a goal
> [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/objective#objective__7)
>
> **AIM**
>
> : a purpose or intention; a desired outcome
> [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/aim#aim__10)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit stronger than a "desire", but some people are seeking their [**Holy Grail**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/holy-grail):

> (informal) any desired ambition or goal - *the Holy Grail of infrared astronomy* (-- Collins)

NB. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holy%20grail) says

> **often not capitalized** :  an object or goal that is sought after for its great significance

It also usually signifies a goal that's particularly hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is **very** strong, it might be called a *craving*.

Answer (score -1):

They are **the objects of {their} desires**.

Replace {their} with the appropriate possessive pronoun for the situation.

Comment: That definitely works, but it's not a single word. It might be a more common phrase than "(some)thing that is desired" though.

Comment: @sumelic - Agreed. And with the update of the example sentence, I think this answer is bordering on useless.