# What is it called when I suddenly ache to do something I usually don't do?

Tags: meaning

Recently I've found myself thinking or longing for stuff that I usually don't even think about.

Example: I don't drink or even like drinking. But sometimes I just get the thought of "1 beer can't hurt". Like I am an addict that's looking for an excuse. I DON'T EVEN LIKE IT. Why am I longing for and excusing something I don't even enjoy?

I would like to know what this feeling / scenerio is called

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you describing a craving or the feeling of guilt/remorse?  If you are seeking help for these issues, I encourage you to call your local or national crisis line.  This is a site for questions about English language and usage.

Comment: Are you thinking of FOMO (Fear of Missing Out)?

Comment: Perhps you have a [yearning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yearning) for something.

Comment: If this is restricted to food and drink, perhaps "sudden craving".

Comment: Sadly, this is another question where answers will almost certainly merely be a subset of those at another thread: [What to call something that we desire?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281688/what-to-call-something-that-we-desire/281859#281859) 'Craving' is probably as near as you'll get, but really needs the 'sudden' modification @Cascabel suggests. It's good to see Cascabel not giving this as an 'answer', I hope because of the 'given as an answer to what may arguably considered a duplicate' consideration.

Answer (score 2):

**whim**

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whim):

First meaning: an odd or capricious notion or desire; a sudden or freakish fancy:
*a sudden whim to take a midnight walk.*

Answer (score 0):

The prime candidate (as reflected in the relevant comments) is that you have a **craving**

> [Merriam Webstrper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craving)
> craving, noun
> an intense, urgent, or abnormal desire or longing
> *a craving for chocolate*
> *a craving for new experiences*

Collins also has

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/craving)
> craving
> in American English
> great or eager desire; yearning

Your specification seems to demand a word with overtones of previously unexpressed desire. This justifies *craving* because in the Cambridge definition we find *urgent* and in the Merriam Webster we have *eager*. Both adjectives are consistent with a sudden or rapidly increasing desire.

The craving sensation is thus urgent, not necessarily restricted to a desire for food or drink, although often associated with these.

Comment: And frequently associated with pregnancy as well.

Comment: What @John said. And [***pregnancy cravings***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pregnancy+cravings%22) very often involve hankering for things the mother-to-be ***wouldn't normally consume*** (or *ever*, in the case of a craving for nibbling on small pieces of coal or raw potato, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "nibbling on small pieces of coal or raw potato"...That borders on _Pica_...